# Unable to generate syntax highlighter from .tmlanguage file in Ace.js

Tags: syntax-highlighting, npm, ace-editor

I have a `.tmlanguage` file that works fine in `Sublime Text 2` and highlights everything as needed. But I'm unable to convert it to the `Ace` highlight rules.

Or rather I convert it but I get errors in `ace.js` main file.

What I do:

1) clone ace repository
2) navigate to `ace/tool` and execute this command in command prompt: `npm install`
3) then execute this command: `node tmlanguage.js <path_to_tmlanguage_file>` and get:

```
parseString is deprecated. Please, use parseStringSync instead.
```

Two files are created in `ace\lib\ace\mode` directory.
4) navigate to `ace` main folder by executing `cd ..`
5) execute `node Makefile.dryice.js full` and get:

```
module.js:340
throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module 'dryice'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\myPath\ace\Makefile.
dryice.js:38:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

6) have to execute npm install in `/ace` main folder and then again call `node Makefile.dryice.js full` to build the project.

Now built files are copied to `ace/build` folder.

Suppose my html file and `/ace` folder are in the same folder. Here is a chunk from html:

```
<script src="ace/build/src-noconflict/ace.js"></script>
<script>
    var editor = ace.edit("editor");
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
    editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/slbeclipse");
</script>
```

In the `ace\build\src-noconflict` folder I have `mode-slbeclipse.js` file.

7) open this html file in chrome (or other browsers) and get (in console tab):

```
Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function       ace.js:8018
```

Here is the 8018th line:

```
this.moveCursorTo(row, column);
```

8) set a breakpoint -> first time it's hit `this.moveCursorTo` is `undefined` but the error is not thrown, the error thrown second time.

9) change that line to:

```
if(this.moveCursorTo)
        {
            this.moveCursorTo(row, column);
        }
```

Than I get error on line 8564: `Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function`:

```
this.getTokenizer = function() {
    if (!this.$tokenizer) {
        this.$highlightRules = new this.HighlightRules();
        // here the exception occures

        this.$tokenizer = new Tokenizer(this.$highlightRules.getRules());
    }
    return this.$tokenizer;
};
```

10) Tried to debug and edit `ace.js` file multiple times - errors in other places occure.

Sublime Text 2 uses `.tmlanguage` properly and everything is highlighted. So, I think, the problem should be in `ace` or (I hope) it's my fault and I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1):

The converter isn't fully automatic, it just extracts regexps from tmlanguage file, and resulting file needs to be fixed manually. (see [here](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/1458#issuecomment-18934593))
I'd suggest to ask for help on that issue.